# Where are keywords such as int, float originally built and defined?

Tags: java, api, primitive-types

I was looking at the Integer Class implementation which wraps int and allows it to use many methods but where are these primitive data types (int, float...) first introduced?

Comment: See the Java Language Specification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/typesValues.html#4.2

Comment: I just wonder where this built-in code located in terms of files, packages, system libraries or under a certain class....?

Comment: They're built into compilers, which are built based on the language specification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they implemented inside JVM
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html

check OpenJDK sources
http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8/